# Not able to download using webclient

Tags: .net

I'm not able download the following link
The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found
Please guide me

```
        string st = "http://www.nseindia.com/content/indices/histdata/S&P%20CNX%20NIFTY15-02-2012-22-03-2012.csv";
        Uri uu = new Uri(st);
        using (WebClient fileReader = new WebClient())
        {
            string tgtDir;
            try
            {
                fileReader.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/zip");
                fileReader.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.12) Gecko/20101026 Firefox/3.6.12 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)");
                tgtDir = @"c:\temp\nif.csv";
                fileReader.DownloadFile(uu, tgtDir);
                fileReader.Dispose();
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                Label1.Text = ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

Comment: If you navigate to the url, is it valid?
(Have to ask the obvious question here)

Comment: I've tried it, and I get a 404 in Chrome...

Comment: That url comes up 404 in my browser as well, so it's not an issue with your WebClient implementation. http://www.nseindia.com/content/indices/histdata/S&P%20CNX%20NIFTY15-02-2012-22-03-2012.csv

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, why are you setting the headers to accept a zip file when you're downloading a CSV?

Secondly, that URL doesn't exist all the time; When I first opened this topic the link worked fine. 2 minutes later I refreshed the page and it gave me a 404, a few minutes after that the link was working again. If I was you I'd be looking for a more stable source of information as this particular file seems to be very unreliable.

Comment: Hi, Thanks, i found another link which is available for download. thanks anyway. And what should i change in the header? coz i'm prity much new to asp.net & c#. Thanks.

Comment: i have just copied these headers from stackoverflow solved question for a downloading a zip file.